# Javascript function is not reading the correct URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a javascript function in my django app to create a dynamic form but when I click on the `Add` Button it is redirecting to the wrong URL

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add_form").click(function(){
   var total = $('.man_class').find('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
   var init = $('.man_class').find('#id_form-INITIAL_FORMS').val();
   var extra = total-init+1;
   var total = parseInt(total, 10)+1;
   var pathname = window.location.pathname.split('/');
   if(pathname.length == 5){
     pk = pathname[2];
   }else{
     pk = 0;
   }
  $.ajax({
        url: 'employee/exams/getset/',
        data : {extra:extra,pk:pk},
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        $('.setclass').append(response);
        $('.man_class').find('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total)
    });
});
```

my url in django app is this:

```
path('employee/', include(([
                             path('exams/getset/', getset , name = 'getset'),], 'pfep'), namespace='emp'))
```

therefore it should go to `employee/exams/getset/` but in the terminal it shows this:

```
Not Found: /exams/getset/
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exams Dashboard</title>
  {% load static %}
  <script src="{% static 'scripts/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'scripts/custom.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1> FFCO: </h1>
        {{ exform }}
        <h2> Inserts:</h2>
        <div class="man_class">
            {{ exformset.management_form }}
        </div>
        <div class="setclass">
        {% for form in exformset %}
        <div class="setelement">
        <div class="sub_id">{{form.id.value}}</div>
          {{form.id}}
          {{form.no_of_inserts_perit.label}}
          {{ form.no_of_inserts_perit }}

            {{form.insert_length.label}}
          {{ form.insert_length }}

            {{form.insert_breadth.label}}
          {{ form.insert_breadth }}

            {{form.insert_height.label}}
          {{ form.insert_height }}

            {{form.insert_type.label}}
          {{ form.insert_type }}

            {{form.insert_weight.label}}
          {{ form.insert_weight }}

            {{form.insert_thickness.label}}
          {{ form.insert_thickness }}

            {{form.insert_gsm.label}}
          {{ form.insert_gsm }}

            {{form.parts_per_layer.label}}
          {{ form.parts_per_layer }}

            {{form.pocket_length.label}}
          {{ form.pocket_length }}

            {{form.pocket_breadth.label}}
          {{ form.pocket_breadth }}

            {{form.pocket_height.label}}
          {{ form.pocket_height }}


          {{form.matrix_detail.label}}
          {{ form.matrix_detail }}<br><br>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <br>
        <button id='add_form' type="button"> Add </button>
      <button id='remove_form' type="button"> Remove </button>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure its not about JavaScript? Have verified that route exist?

Comment: @Tito Yes, I have checked that. the route exists, also shouldn't it give this `employee/exams/getset/` as an error if it doesn't exists ?

Comment: @Phil Yes, it is a button in another template and the action is `<form method="POST">`

Comment: And when you load this page in your browser, what is the URL?

Comment: @Phil I cannot directly access the url as `extra` and `pk` makes a complete URL

Comment: @Phil I can see this in the console `http://127.0.0.1:8000/exams/getset/?extra=2&pk=exams` when I click the add more button

Comment: Just an example please. Make up values. You're using a relative path with `url: 'employee/exams/getset/'` so it's relevant to your question

Comment: You've hard-coded URL in ajax.  which is a relative url. That means ajax will append this  'employee/exams/getset/' after current browser url. Use root level url like  '/employee/exams/getset/'

Comment: @Tito actually that is the problem, when I click on the `Add` button it shows `http://127.0.0.1:8000/exams/getset/?extra=2&pk=exams` in the Console.. So it is taking `extra` and `pk` values but not adding `employee/` as stated in the code

Comment: How come there is a redirect? From your code I can see a button sending ajax request. what happens when you replace your Ajax code with this one:
$.ajax({
        url: '/employee/exams/getset/',
        data : {extra:extra,pk:pk},
    });

Comment: @Tito In terminal it shows `Not Found: /exams/getset/` even with the `url: '/employee/exams/getset/'`  I tried gibberish in the url but still the same error no matter what the url is

Comment: Then its originating for somewhere else or cached. Try changing button id(add_form) in html and JS. Make sure you've disabled cache from Network tab of Developer tools.